# Solving a system of polynomial equations

Tags: equation-solving

I am a beginner with Mathematica and this is my first post.
In fact, I have 5 polynomial equations with 5 unknown: `q1,q2,q3,q4` and `lamda`.

```
288.4054*q1^3+(-66.31054027*q2-58.45307251*q3+17.65449803*q4)*q1^2+(-285.0173022*q2^2+(17.74282580*q3+37.16464964*q4)*q2-285.3115843*q3^2-.4401951214*q3*q4+288.1843939*q4^2+1.000000172*lamda)*q1+22.10352*q2^3+(18.58232206*q3-8.871413528*q4)*q2^2+(21.27303289*q3^2-2.480672232*q3*q4-21.27303250*q4^2)*q2+19.45320102*q3^3-5.953122346*q3^2*q4-19.42973362*q3*q4^2+5.875423065*q4^3=0 

288.4054*q2^3+66.31054027*q1*q2^2-17.65449803*q2^2*q3-58.45307251*q2^2*q4-285.0173022*q2*q1^2+37.16464964*q1*q2*q3-17.74282580*q1*q2*q4+288.1843939*q2*q3^2+.4401951214*q2*q3*q4-285.3115843*q2*q4^2+1.000000172*lamda*q2+18.58232206*q4*q1^2-22.10352*q1^3+8.871413528*q3*q1^2-2.480672232*q1*q3*q4+21.27303250*q1*q3^2-21.27303289*q1*q4^2-19.42973362*q3^2*q4-5.875423065*q3^3+5.953122346*q3*q4^2+19.45320102*q4^3=0

287.4838*q3^3+(58.35962330*q1-17.62626852*q2-1.722386624*q4)*q3^2+(-285.3115535*q1^2+(42.54607400*q2-11.90624409*q4)*q1+288.1843939*q2^2-38.85947420*q2*q4-287.4815373*q4^2+1.000000172*lamda)*q3-19.48436*q1^3+(8.871412261*q2-.2200976687*q4)*q1^2+(18.58232765*q2^2-2.480672976*q2*q4-19.42973905*q4^2)*q1-5.884832024*q2^3+.2200977984*q2^2*q4+5.953122091*q2*q4^2+.5741289018*q4^3=0

287.4838*q4^3+(17.62626852*q1+58.35962330*q2+1.722386624*q3)*q4^2+(288.1843939*q1^2+(-42.54607400*q2-38.85947420*q3)*q1-285.3115535*q2^2+11.90624409*q2*q3-287.4815373*q3^2+1.000000172*lamda)*q4+5.884832*q1^3+(18.58232274*q2-.2200978366*q3)*q1^2+(-8.871411487*q2^2-2.480672306*q2*q3-5.953122062*q3^2)*q1-19.48435509*q2^3+.2200975094*q2^2*q3-19.42973415*q2*q3^2-.5741288603*q3^3=0

q1^2+q2^2+q3^2+q4^2-1=0
```

How can I solve this problem please?

Comment: notice, you need to use `==` and not `=` there. One is equality and the other is assignment ! I corrected this below.

Answer (score 3):

```
eq1 = 288.4054*
     q1^3 + (-66.31054027*q2 - 58.45307251*q3 + 17.65449803*q4)*
     q1^2 + (-285.0173022*q2^2 + (17.74282580*q3 + 37.16464964*q4)*
        q2 - 285.3115843*q3^2 - .4401951214*q3*q4 + 
       288.1843939*q4^2 + 1.000000172*lamda)*q1 + 
    22.10352*q2^3 + (18.58232206*q3 - 8.871413528*q4)*
     q2^2 + (21.27303289*q3^2 - 2.480672232*q3*q4 - 21.27303250*q4^2)*
     q2 + 19.45320102*q3^3 - 5.953122346*q3^2*q4 - 
    19.42973362*q3*q4^2 + 5.875423065*q4^3 == 0;
eq2 = 288.4054*q2^3 + 66.31054027*q1*q2^2 - 17.65449803*q2^2*q3 - 
    58.45307251*q2^2*q4 - 285.0173022*q2*q1^2 + 
    37.16464964*q1*q2*q3 - 17.74282580*q1*q2*q4 + 
    288.1843939*q2*q3^2 + .4401951214*q2*q3*q4 - 
    285.3115843*q2*q4^2 + 1.000000172*lamda*q2 + 
    18.58232206*q4*q1^2 - 22.10352*q1^3 + 8.871413528*q3*q1^2 - 
    2.480672232*q1*q3*q4 + 21.27303250*q1*q3^2 - 
    21.27303289*q1*q4^2 - 19.42973362*q3^2*q4 - 5.875423065*q3^3 + 
    5.953122346*q3*q4^2 + 19.45320102*q4^3 == 0;
eq3 = 287.4838*
     q3^3 + (58.35962330*q1 - 17.62626852*q2 - 1.722386624*q4)*
     q3^2 + (-285.3115535*q1^2 + (42.54607400*q2 - 11.90624409*q4)*
        q1 + 288.1843939*q2^2 - 38.85947420*q2*q4 - 
       287.4815373*q4^2 + 1.000000172*lamda)*q3 - 
    19.48436*q1^3 + (8.871412261*q2 - .2200976687*q4)*
     q1^2 + (18.58232765*q2^2 - 2.480672976*q2*q4 - 19.42973905*q4^2)*
     q1 - 5.884832024*q2^3 + .2200977984*q2^2*q4 + 
    5.953122091*q2*q4^2 + .5741289018*q4^3 == 0;
eq4 = 287.4838*
     q4^3 + (17.62626852*q1 + 58.35962330*q2 + 1.722386624*q3)*
     q4^2 + (288.1843939*q1^2 + (-42.54607400*q2 - 38.85947420*q3)*
        q1 - 285.3115535*q2^2 + 11.90624409*q2*q3 - 
       287.4815373*q3^2 + 1.000000172*lamda)*q4 + 
    5.884832*q1^3 + (18.58232274*q2 - .2200978366*q3)*
     q1^2 + (-8.871411487*q2^2 - 2.480672306*q2*q3 - 
       5.953122062*q3^2)*q1 - 
    19.48435509*q2^3 + .2200975094*q2^2*q3 - 
    19.42973415*q2*q3^2 - .5741288603*q3^3 == 0;
eq5 = q1^2 + q2^2 + q3^2 + q4^2 - 1 == 0;
```

Then

```
NSolve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5}, {q1, q2, q3, q4, lamda}, Reals]
```

gives these solutions

[image: Mathematica graphics]